# CellClick event of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Even if we click the header of a DataGridView, cell click event is getting fired. How to stop it from firing?

Comment: IMHO, you should try to handle the event properly instead of preventing the execution of it in casual cases.

Answer (score 3):

Compare the `RowIndex` and `ColIndex` if they have -1 (header column/row index) value then `ignore` it.

```
testDataGridView.CellClick += (senderObject, eventArgs) =>
 {
  if (eventArgs.RowIndex == -1 || eventArgs.ColumnIndex == -1)
    return;
  //statements here
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1)
        {                
            return;                
        }
       //Write your code here ...
    }
```